# Does a person in spiritual path gets his worldly desires fulfilled?

Tags: spiritual-level

I would like to know if a person in spiritual path gets his worldly desires fulfilled. Because in the path of spirituality, the person gets away from desires slowly, however if he wills to stick to a particular desire, then that will be an obstacle for him in the path of spirituality.

This man is said to have vital energy which he uses for spiritual destiny. Now, can that energy be used or help him to fulfill his material desire?

Comment: think of a tree, and then its shadow. A man going after the shadow fruit in the shadow tree gets nothing. Whereas the being going after the real fruit in the real tree gets it. But also, his shadow gets the shadow fruit! Similarly go after material desires, and finally you get nothing, GO after God, and you end up with everything. Said by Sai Baba. Praying to God for defeat of others is Tamas, Praying to God for worldly boons is Rajas, Praying to God for taking care of us is Sattva. Praying to God for God and God only is Nirakara Bhakti, Supreme devotion, True Surrender and ultimate bliss!

Comment: @Sai: Wondefully explained by Sai Baba! And brother, your comments often have a great lesson with them.

Answer (score 2):

All desires are ultimately bestowed by the Supreme Lord.

> Katha Upanishad 2.2.13:
>
> nityo nityanam
>
> cetanas cetananam
>
> eko bahunam
>
> yo vidadhati kaman
>
> He is the prime eternal among all eternals. He is the supreme living
>   entity of all living entities, and He alone is maintaining all life

If some one is on the spiritual path and yet desires material things He will fulfill the desires of a devotee in such a way that the devotee gradually loses interest in any more material things. In [Srimad Bhagavatam 5.19.27](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/19/27) it is mentioned that:

> The Supreme Personality of Godhead fulfills the material desires of a
>   devotee who approaches Him with such motives, but He does not bestow
>   benedictions upon the devotee that will cause him to demand more
>   benedictions again. However, the Lord willingly gives the devotee
>   shelter at His own lotus feet, even though such a person does not
>   aspire for it, and that shelter satisfies all his desires. That is the
>   Supreme Personality’s special mercy.

Commenting on the above verse Srila Prabhupada writes:

> “Whether one is freed from all material desires, is full of material
>   desires, or desires to become one with the Supreme, he should engage
>   in devotional service.” ([Bhagavatam 2.3.20](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/3/10)) In this way, not only will the devotee’s
>   desires be fulfilled, but the day will come when he
>   will have no other desire than to serve the lotus feet of the Lord.
>   One who engages in the service of the Lord with some motive is called
>   a sakama-bhakta, and one who serves the Lord without any motives is
>   called an akama-bhakta. Krsna is so merciful that He turns a
>   sakama-bhakta into an akama-bhakta

We see this in the example of Dhruva where he performs austerities for material opulence but he later loses interest in material things. Kardama also performs tapasya to get a wife and Lord Vishnu grants Him the boon to get Devahuti as his wife. The Lord also personally becomes his son as Kapila. Later both Kardama and Devahuti attain perfection.

Comment: If a person doesn't ask the Lord explicitly **always** but still has a (only one) worldly desire in his heart and no other desires, will he fulfill it? i.e. he doesn't ask him every time he performs rituals, but only a few times, when he isn't performing the rituals.